# Have problems in importing classes from another file in parent folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

The files I need in the directory look like

`face/util/load_data.py`

`face/preprocessing.py`

preprocessing.py defines the classes `FaceDetector`, `FaceAligner` and the method `clip_to_range`

I want to import these classes into load_data.py
I am trying to execute this statement **inside load_data.py**

```
from preprocessing import FaceDetector, FaceAligner, clip_to_range
```

I am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils/load_data.py", line 7, in <module>
    from preprocessing import FaceDetector, FaceAligner, clip_to_range
ImportError: cannot import name 'FaceDetector'
```

Can you please tell me how to correctly import these classes?

Comment: Which file is executed first?

Comment: I am executing load_data.py only

Comment: python3 utils/load_data.py

Comment: check for a circular import as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `__init__.py`

Which will allow you to import face module, then you can import like,

```
from face.preprocessing import FaceDetector, FaceAligner, clip_to_range
```

**Update:**
Another way is to insert module in sys.path,

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 

import preprocessing
```

Answer (score 0):

move `preprocessing.py` to util directory.

Look for the file in the path of the executed file.

If you do not want to change the directory structure. Add the following code.

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)
```

Import is possible regardless of directory structure.

You will can solved.